# how to change the default behaviour of 'WhoDidiT' in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using 'WhoDidiT' in my model to insert user_id. Its working fine. 
Now i need to insert a different user_id instead of the logged in user_id.
Is there any way to insert the different user_id without modifying 'WhoDidiT'

```
var $actsAs = array(
    'WhoDidIt'=>array(
                     'created_by_field'=>'created_by',
                     'modified_by_field'=>'modified_by'
                ),

 );
```

Comment: You should also state what source you are taking the behavior from. Also why would you want to do that? You might have to modify the behavior then. As there should be always the logged in user added here by default.

Comment: Solved it using $this->Model->saveField('created_by',$user_id);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you save, you can update that specific field

```
$this->Model->saveField('created_by',$id);
```

this will do the trick